# Where to find wallpaper samples online?

Tags: wallpaper

I want to put a wallpaper in my home office and my kid room, Are there famous websites to see samples online and take some ideas from there? also is it possible to buy them online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two major retailers in the US are [Home Depot](http://www.homedepot.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Navigation?storeId=10051&categoryID=528794&langId=-1&catalogId=10053&navFlow=3&searchRedirect=wallpaper&cm_sp=searchredirect-_-wallpaper-_-x-_-x&locStoreNum=4702&marketID=44) and [Lowe's](http://www.lowes.com/pl_Wallpaper_4294929280_4294937087_?UserSearch=wallpaper&langId=-1&storeId=10151&y=0&catalogId=10051&N=0&x=0&newSearch=true&ddkey=http%3aSearchCatalog), both of whom carry a wide selection of wallpapers.

Another good place to look would be [amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com/gp/search/ref=sr_tc_2_1?rh=n%3A2242314011%2Ck%3Awallpaper&keywords=wallpaper&ie=UTF8&qid=1289540272&sr=8-2-tc#%2Fref%3Dsr_hi_3%3Frh%3Dn%253A228013%252Cn%253A%2521468240%252Cn%253A228899%252Cn%253A2242314011%26ie%3DUTF8%26qid%3D1289540300&enc=1).